# Запятая перед словом "необходимо"

Tags: пунктуация

Доброго времени суток. Пишу техническую документацию и столкнулся с проблемой - запятая перед словом "необходимо".
Примеры.
1. Для входа в программу необходимо нажать по кнопке.
2. Для работы с программой необходимо авторизоваться.
3. Для создания задачи необходимо нажать на кнопку.
4. Для поиска задачи по содержанию необходимо ввести искомое слово или словосочетание.
5. Для того чтобы заполнить закладку, необходимо нажать на кнопку.

В каких случаях запятая нужна, а в каких нет?

Answer (score 3):

**Запятая ставится только в сложноподчиненном предложении 5 с придаточном цели** (союз ДЛЯ ТОГО ЧТОБЫ): Для того чтобы заполнить закладку, необходимо нажать на кнопку.

Остальные предложения являются **простыми** (односоставными, безличными, нет подлежащего, только сказуемое), запятая в них не ставится (при отсутствии обособленных оборотов и однородных членов).

Обратим внимание на то, что предложение 5 легко перестраивается в простое предложение: **Для заполнения закладки необходимо нажать на кнопку.** Для изменения структуры предложения нужно заменить глагол отглагольным существительным, тогда ДЛЯ в качестве предлога будет относиться к отглагольному существительному.

Примечание.

Необходимо нажать, необходимо авторизоваться и т.д.  — это **составное глагольное сказуемое**: модальная связка "необходимо" + основной глагол в неопределенной форме.

Answer (score 1):

Запятая нужна только в предложении 5 — сложноподчиненное предложение. Для остальных примеров, рискуя навлечь гнев некоторых пунктуальных участников и модераторов (которые, впрочем, вряд ли оспорят правильность ответа), рискну повторить: нет причин для постановки запятой, и это вполне достаточное объяснение.

Comment: Не является ответом: "нет причин для постановки запятой, и это вполне достаточное объяснение". При этом сам подход формальный, нет понимания о том, что связывает эти 5 предложений, сходных по структуре, но с разной грамматикой.